# Session expired

Tags: php, session, plesk, limesurvey

I'm trying to set up the server to increase the lifetime session to 2 hours to be able to save surveys (Limesurvey) after some time of inactivity. If I try to save after 45 minutes it shows up an error message saying that the session has expired.

I have been reading a lot to find solutions but what I have found so far, didn't work. Probably because I'm missing something.

**This is what I have:**

- Plesk 12.5.30
- Limesurvey 2.06+ Build 150831
- PHP 5.3.10

The settings in **config-defaults.php** (Limesurvey) have:

```
$config['iSessionExpirationTime'] = 7200;
```

**2 hours** which is ok, is what I want but does not work. So I thought that my server settings were overriding the Limesurvey settings. So I went to ***plesk > domains***, selected my domain and clicked on PHP settings, scrolled down and added to the **"additional instructions"** these two lines:

```
session.cookie_lifetime = 7200
session.gc_maxlifetime = 7200
```

So now all my additional instructions looks like this:

```
max_input_vars = 5000
suhosin.memory_limit = 128
suhosin.post.max_value_length = 5000000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000
suhosin.request.max_value_length = 5000000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000
suhosin.simulation = 1
session.cookie_lifetime = 7200
session.gc_maxlifetime = 7200
```

But it didn't work anyways, I'm still having the same error when trying to save a survey when 45 minutes have elapsed.

Any help would be great.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache after making these changes

Comment: @RiggsFolly Is not the same restarting the server?

Comment: I am not PLESK Expert, but if you chnage php config i.e. `php.ini` it is normal to have to restart Apache to make it pick up the amended ini information. Unless you are using FastCGI, then I suppose it would not be necessary to restart?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think I'm using FastCGI but it didn't work anyways, after restarting the server neither. Now I'm trying to edit the php.ini directly and not through **"Additional Instructions"** to see if that is the problem and maybe that field is not working as expected.

Comment: @RiggsFolly anything I have tried worked so far...anyone else have an idea?

Comment: Did you check the expiration time of the cookie that contains the session id ?

Comment: @JohnSaucisse I'm really new with this topics, can you please guide me how to check that?

Comment: @Panconjugo Use [this tutorial on wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/View-Cookies) to list cookies of your website. Then search for the cookie named `PHPSESSID` (it's the *default* name of the cookie that contains the session id, most of the time). Then check its expiration time. If it's smaller than `session.cookie_lifetime`, then there probably is something that overrides this value.

Comment: @Kadriles I followed that tutorial but there's no cookie named PHPSESSID

Comment: @Panconjugo It may have a different name, maybe *sessionid*... Try to your cookies one by one.

Comment: @Kadriles sorry it was **phpsessid**, I just forgot to open the page I want to check. Anyways that cookie expires in 2 hours which is good, so the changes I made above **(session.cookie_lifetime = 7200, session.gc_maxlifetime = 7200)** worked but after some days and not right away, I'm not sure why that happens. Now when I test a survey (Limesurvey) after 1 hour and half of inactivity it works **(I have it for 2 hours).** But another person still have that problem and when she tries to save a survey after 30 minutes, Limesurvey still display that error saying that the session has expired.

Answer (score 0):

Check cron tasks:

```
cat /etc/cron.d/php5

# /etc/cron.d/php5: crontab fragment for php5
#  This purges session files in session.save_path older than X,
#  where X is defined in seconds as the largest value of
#  session.gc_maxlifetime from all your SAPI php.ini files
#  or 24 minutes if not defined.  The script triggers only
#  when session.save_handler=files.
#
#  WARNING: The scripts tries hard to honour all relevant
#  session PHP options, but if you do something unusual
#  you have to disable this script and take care of your
#  sessions yourself.

# Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean
```

Comment: Not sure how to check that, can you please guide me? I have putty and just wrote **cat /etc/cron.d/php5** then it showed me some information like this: **09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete**

Comment: Command in your /etc/cron.d/php5 check every 9 and 39 minutes if file /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean exist than it checks for how old session files in /var/lib/php5 and delete files which age greater than value defined in /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime

Comment: You can check and delete /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime or increase value in /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime . Beware of deleting /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime - session files may flood your free disk space.

Comment: Sorry but I'm really new with this kind of things, can you guide me a little? How can I check that to increase it?? just writting  **/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime** in Putty??

Comment: Yes, open it in vim  /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime and update digit value.

Comment: I got this code after opening what you said: `max=1440

if which php5 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    for sapi in apache2 apache2filter cgi fpm; do
        if [ -e /etc/php5/${sapi}/php.ini ]; then
            cur=$(php5 -c /etc/php5/${sapi}/php.ini -d "error_reporting='~E_ALL'" -r 'print ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime");')
            [ -z "$cur" ] && cur=0
            [ "$cur" -gt "$max" ] && max=$cur
        fi
    done
else
    for ini in /etc/php5/*/php.ini /etc/php5/conf.d/*.ini; do
        cur=$(sed -n -e 's/^[[:space:]]*session.gc_maxlifetime[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\([0-9]\+\).*$/\1/...
`

Comment: Also, if I only type /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime and press enter in putty I got this number **120** why is that?

Comment: It's default 120 seconds to clean up session files. Try to update this value to 7200.

Comment: Sorry but could you explain me how to do that in putty? as I said I'm really new at it and can't find how to do it on internet.

Comment: `echo '7200' > /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime`

Comment: I typed that on putty, pressed enter and then to check I just typed only **/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime** and it showed me this: **/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime: Line 1: 7200: no command found.** is that ok?

Comment: Yes, because '/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime' it's not a command. You can see file's content by commands `cat /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime` or `less /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime` (use 'q' to exit)

Comment: Thanks so much for helping, I have learned a lot about it during this time. I have made those changes but still no luck...I dont understand well this behavior, I tested the session being inactive for 1 hour and 55 minutes (before it expires at 2 hours) and when I save (my survey in limesurvey) worked as expected, but then I leave for 1 hour more of inactivity and when I save again it expires. Shouldn't it restart again from 0?

Comment: Think it's better to ask limesurvey community at https://www.limesurvey.org/community-services/forums

Answer (score 0):

Usually the session directory is shared by all applications on the same webspace.
So if you have other applications (CMS) running they might set the session timeout shorter and so the LimeSurvey sessions get kicked, too.

Comment: Actually yes, there are some other cms installed in the server, old ones without use and the current one **"CMS Made Simple"**. How can I check that, can you guide me please?